# Refactoring: Extracting interface in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, refactoring

I'm trying to extract the interface `IObjectsCollection` for the `BeamsCollection` and `ColumnsCollection`. But I'm stuck.

Both `Beam` and `Column` derive from `SObject` class.

```
public class BeamsCollection : IObjectsCollection
{
    public List<Beam> SObjects{ get; private set; }

    public BeamsCollection ()
    {
        SObjects = new List<Beam>();
    }

    public void Add(Beam beam)
    {
        SObjects.Add(beam);
    }
}

public class ColumnsCollection : IObjectsCollection
{
    public List<Column> SObjects{ get; private set; }

    public ColumnsCollection ()
    {
        SObjects= new List<Column>();
    }

    public void Add(Column column)
    {
        SObjects.Add(column);
    }
}

public interface IObjectsCollection
{
    List<SObject> SObjects{ get; }
    void Add(SObject sobject);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to extract the interface. Updated the question.

Comment: They have different methods, so how do you plan to create the interface? You already have one version of it, what is the problem and how do you want it to be done?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Maybe I'm missing something here, I thought maybe if I could define an interface it'll be a good design.

Comment: You can make the interface generic `IObjectsCollection<T>` and T will be substituted in place of Column/Beam. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @Vahid If you don't need an interface, it doesn't really add anything to the design. It doesn't become better based on the number of interfaces really. Generic interface was mentioned and that is probably the way to go if you really need an interface.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks Sami, the solution you and Ric provided worked. I was trying to use interfaces, so that I can keep a uniform implementation in the classes that implement the interface. Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
public interface IObjectsCollection<T> where T : SObject
{
    List<T> Items{ get; }
    void Add(T item);
}

public class BeamsCollection : IObjectsCollection<Beam>
{
    public List<Beam> Items { get; private set; }

    public BeamsCollection ()
    {
        Items = new List<Beam>();
    }

    public void Add(Beam item)
    {
        Items.Add(beam);
    }
}

public class ColumnsCollection : IObjectsCollection<Column>
{
    public List<Column> Items { get; private set; }

    public ColumnsCollection ()
    {
        Items = new List<Column>();
    }

    public void Add(Column item)
    {
        Items.Add(column);
    }
}
```

Or, you could just define a generic class so that you dont need to keep adding new implementations of your `IObjectsCollection`

```
public class MyObjectsCollection<T> where T : SObject
{
 //....rest of class ommitted.
}
```

then use it:

```
MyObjectsCollection<Beam> m1 = new MyObjectsCollection<Beam>();
m1.Items.Add(new Beam());

MyObjectsCollection<Column> m2 = new MyObjectsCollection<Column>();
m2.Items.Add(new Column());
```

Comment: I was trying to use interfaces, so that I can keep a uniform implementation in the classes that implement the interface. Is it a bad idea?

Comment: Well it depends. If all of the classes implementing the interface do nothing else other than expose the collection and add to it, then if you have many classes you project could get bloated. Or, just define a single class that allows you to do it, seem my latest edit.